# Experience Editor Button Field Editor Button with Image Field Uploading in Client Language

Tags: experience-editor, multilingual

I have a field editor button made from the template in core `/sitecore/templates/System/WebEdit/Field Editor Button` which has an image field id in the field Fields. When a user clicks on the edit frame, clicks the experience editor button and chooses browse -> upload media the image uploaded will be uploaded in the user's `Client Language` rather than the language of the page they are on. Is there a way to configure this to use the page's language rather than the user's client language?

It's probably also worth mentioning that this is applied to a `View rendering`'s `Experience Editor Buttons` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported this to Sitecore and it is a bug that can be [fixed with this patch](https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/vxjdzd843tralqlcjsm0643qvni2h4zj). The patch is `Sitecore.Support.189805`. The supported versions of the linked version are `Sitecore CMS 8.2 rev. 170407 (Update-3)` and `Sitecore CMS 8.2 rev. 170728 (Update-5)`.

Comment: Can you add details of the bug and reference number. Without this info, and if the linked download breaks, this answer is useless to anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Yeah good call.